# Rails 3.1 failure with devise plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:controller=>"devise/items"}):
    8: </head>
    9: <body>
    10:   <nav>
    11:   <%= link_to_unless_current "Home", :controller => "items", :action => "index" %> |
    12:   <%= link_to_unless_current "About us", :controller => "site", :action => "about" %> | 
    13:   <%= link_to_unless_current "Contact us", :controller => "site", :action => "contact" %> 
    14:   </nav>
```

I'm trying to make a simple rails online shop. I included devise model User(strictly following Railcasts tutorial) and when I'm trying to go to /users/sign_in I get this error in the server log. I don't understand why it renders "devise/items" when I'm typing localhost:3000/users/sign_in.

Added:
routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users
get "site/about"
get "site/contact"

resources :items
root :to => "items#index"
```

Comment: can you post the contents of your config/routes.rb file?

Comment: What does your `routes.rb` look like?

Comment: OK, and how does the output of `rake routes` look like?

Comment: it looks fine - showing all the possibilities including /users/sign_in /users/sign_out /users/password, etc.

Comment: you created the user model? but I don't see "resources :users" in your routes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it adding a "/" before your controller name.

```
<%= link_to_unless_current "Home", :controller => "/items", :action => "index" %>
```